# URL is updating but the Component is not displayed

Tags: reactjs, javascript-objects, react-router-dom

I've been racking my head over this for about 2 weeks now. I'm completely out of my depth and I feel like I should give up every time I try but here I am, pushing forward!

I've created a Route in my App component which is working perfectly and looks like this -

```
function App() {

  const location = useLocation();

  return (

    <div className="App">
      <Navigation />
      <Copyright />
      <Button linkTo="/hire" btnText="Hire me" /> 

      <div className="page-wrap flex_center">
        <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter initial={false}>
          <Switch location={location} key={location.pathname}>
            <Route path="/projects" exact component={Projects}/>
            <Route path="/hire" exact component={Hire}/>
            <Route path="/about" exact component={About}/>
            <Route path="/" exact key="/" component={Home}/>
          </Switch>
        </AnimatePresence>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Inside the Projects component I want to display a list of links which then display content based on some object data (There will be multiple projects and the number of projects will change regularly)

Here's the Projects component -

```
const Projects = () => {

  const location = useLocation();

  const ProjectData = [
    {
      id: "project-one",
      name: "Project 1",
      description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin molestie.",
    },
    {
      id: "project-two",
      name: "Project 2",
      description: "Mauris finibus, massa eu tempor volutpat, magna dolor euismod dolor.",
    },
  ];

  const { url } = useRouteMatch();
  const linkList = ProjectData.map((project) => {

    return (
      <li key={project.id}>
        <Link to={`${url}/${project.id}`}>{project.name}</Link>
      </li>
    );
    
  });

  return (

    <Switch location={location} key={location.pathname}>
      <Route path={`${url}/:projectId`}>
          <Project data={ProjectData} />
      </Route>
      <Route exact path={url}>
        <ul>{linkList}</ul>
      </Route>
    </Switch>

  );
};

export default Projects;
```

The final part is the Project component which handles the data

```
const Project = ({ data }) => {

  const { projectId } = useParams();
  const project = data.find(p => p.id === String(projectId));
  
  let projectData;
  let history = useHistory()
  
  if (project) {
    projectData = (
      <div>
        <h3>{project.name}</h3>
        <p>{project.description}</p>
      </div>
    );

  } else {
    projectData = <h2> Sorry but this project doesn't exist.</h2>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      {projectData}
      <button type="button" onClick={() => history.goBack()}>go back</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Project;
```

Now I've laid everything out, the issue I'm having is that the URL updates when the links are clicked but the component doesn't render in the browser, unless I physically refresh the page.

Initially I thought the Routes in my App component were the issue but after some reading I don't think that's the case. Due to insufficient understanding of more dynamic routes, I think I'm just going in circles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 15, remove the `exact` boolean prop.

E.g.

```js
// Before
<Route path="/projects" exact component={Projects}/>

// After
<Route path="/projects" component={Projects}/>
```

The whole notion of sub-routing should be handled by the child component.